# Stop VSCode from "greening out" my Dust / HTML code after "#" symbol

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, dust.js

I have some Dust templates that I'm looking at in VS Code. On 1 computer, if there is a "#" symbol, the code after it turns green as if it were commented out.

For instance:

```
<div id="someDiv">
Some text
<#someThing>
<div id="anotherDiv">
More text
</div>
</div>
```

Everything from "<#someThing>" down would be greened out.

What could be causing this? Since it's only happening on 1 out of 3 computers I'm running VS Code on, makes it feel like it might be some extension, but is there an easy way to tell VS Code not to do this?

Comment: This soulds like something an extension or color theme could cause. Have you tried disabling them and making sure you're using the default color theme?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all the cosmetic extensions and adding them one by one to see what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

DustJS supports added Syntax Highlighting to **any** DustJS files.
Maybe DustJS Syntax Highlighting set `<#something>` or `#` as a comment string or something. [Here For More Info](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzkabanCoders.dustjs&ssr=false#overview).

Comment: I didn't have any Dust.js extensions installed in VSCode. I actually just added one to see if it helped, but it had no impact.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what caused this issue in the first place, but installing the DustJS extension and changing "Language Mode" to DustJS fixed the issue. Note, I installed some other Dust extensions and had tried selecting "dust" as the language and that didn't work. Only the "DustJS" one fixed it.